# jQuery: Click on element excluding clicks on child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling to get the right jQuery selectors for clicking on a certain element. Here is the HTML that I have:

```
<label class="title-label" for="me">Some Title<i class="fa fa-times del-class"></i></label>
```

I have two separate jQuery listeners:

```
$(document).on("click", ".title-label", function (e) { //magic happens here
```

and another one:

```
$(document).on("click", ".del-class", function (e) { //the whole label gets deleted
```

When I click on the label I send `.ajax` request to the server and magic happens. There is also a little `i` icon for deleting the whole label which also works. However, when I click on the `.del-class` icon, it first triggers the click on the `.title-label` which sends the request to the server, the magic happens and then the label gets deleted. The icon needs to stay within the label but when I click on it, it should not trigger the click on the label and the magic but delete the label right away.

I tried various attempts to include the `:not` selector like this:

```
:not('.del-class') .title-label
```

But both always get triggered. Any clue what the right selector would be in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".title-label", function(e) {
  console.log('title-label click');
});

$(document).on("click", ".del-class", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();  //Add
  console.log('del-class click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="title-label" for="me">Some Title<i class="fa fa-times del-class"> Other text </i></label>
```

Comment: Possibly worth noting that even though the click has *already* bubbled to the parent element, jQuery's event delegation handling makes it seem as though it hasn't when you do this.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think that `stopPropagation` will do the trick but it seems to be working. Thank you!

Comment: `so that the event on the parent will not excute on the child` . It's the other way around :)

Comment: Ohh.. I rephrased it to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `event.target` is or not the icon and do your stuff in the `if/else` statement.

See below

```js
$(document).on("click", ".title-label", function(e) {
let tgt = e.target
      if (!$(tgt).is('.del-class ') ) {
          console.log('do magic now')
        }
        else {
          console.log('delete label straight away')
        }
    //or
    
    !$(tgt).is('.del-class ') ? console.log('do magic now') : console.log('delete label straight away')
        
})
```

```css
i {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: Red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="title-label" for="me">Some Title<i class="fa fa-times del-class"></i></label>
```

Answer (score -2):

If I get it right, you have 2 elements and one of them is inside the other one, if you need 2 separate listeners, you need to use event.stopPropagation() on the child one.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/239539/

```
$('.parent_div_click').on('click',function(event){
    console.log('click in parent');
});
$('.child_i_click').on('click',function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('click in child');
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: it's the same answer as @Eddie but not with a working snippet and not with the (little) code the OP provided